# Can I find out how many people are using my WP plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering is it allowed and also what's the best way to track how many users are currently using and running your WordPress plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really allowed without user permission, best bet is to check your plugin stats for active versions and download counts.

> No "phoning home" without user's informed consent. This seemingly
>   simple rule actually covers several different aspects:
>
> - No unauthorized collection of user data. For example, sending the admin's email address back to your own servers without permission of
>     the user is not allowed; but asking the user for an email address and
>     collecting if they choose to submit it is fine. All actions taken in
>     this respect MUST be of the user's doing, not automatically done by
>     the plugin.
> - All images and scripts shown should be part of the plugin. These should be loaded locally. If the plugin does require that data is
>     loaded from an external site (such as blocklists) this should be made
>     clear in the plugin's admin screens or description. The point is that
>     the user must be informed of what information is being sent where.

Source: [Detailed Plugin Guidelines - Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/guidelines/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check how many people have downloaded your WP plugin?

Comment: There's a difference between how many people have downloaded it and how many are still using or have it installed and not deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a callback to your server, but many users won't like it.

Comment: It's against WordPress Guidelines.

Comment: More than "not like", "denounce" is more apropriate!